# date_add() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to fetch the current date and add 7 to it to calculate date of weekly installments for a project. while doing so i encountered a problem:-

> date_add() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given

The line causing me this error is

```
$loan->nextpremiumdate=date_add(date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"),date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 days"));
```

i am using laravel framework. and nextpremiumdate is column in my loan table.

Comment: `$loan->nextpremiumdate=date_add(new DateTime("Y-m-d h:i:sa"),date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 days"));`  or `$loan->nextpremiumdate=date_add(new DateTime("now"),date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 days"));`

Comment: Please try that code: (new \DateTime())->add(
    \DateInterval::createFromDateString("1 days")
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model table declare that you want "nextpremiumdate" to be managed as a date:

```
public class Loan extends Model {
       protected $dates = [ "nextpremiumdate" ];
}
```

Then laravel will return the field as a `Carbon` date and you can just do:

```
$loan->nextpremiumdate = $loan->nextpremiumdate->addDays(7);
```

You can refer to the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) or the [carbon docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for more details.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked fine and got to know about a new thing as well :)